# Speed up image processing of Paperclip in Acceptance Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, rspec, paperclip, capybara

When running `capybara` feature specs I can see lots of Slow factory notices which are populated by `factory_girl`. These Slow factory things heavy slow down the feature specs, I think, even feature specs are intrinsic slow specs. Then I had some inspect and found out most of the Slow factory was caused by `paperclip`. We had model using paperclip here:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :asset do
    image Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/sample.jpg').open
  end
end
```

So I wonder if there's a way like test mode for `paperclip` to speed up tests. I have simple solution here: Just copy the original file instead of actually crop it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the way out to achieve this, see this code:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :asset do
    image_file_name { 'sample.jpg' }
    image_content_type 'image/jpeg'
    image_file_size 256

    after(:create) do |asset|
      image_file = Rails.root.join("spec/fixtures/#{asset.image_file_name}")

      # cp test image to direcotries
      [:original, :medium, :thumb].each do |size|
        dest_path = asset.image.path(size)
        `mkdir -p #{File.dirname(dest_path)}`
        `cp #{image_file} #{dest_path}`
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Manually `cp` the test image to the real asset image paths in a factory_girl after create hook. It works like a charm.

Comment: Just a note for others. I could only use the `after(:build)` callback, but that didn’t have access to an id. Fixed this by adding a sequence to id like this: `sequence(:id){|n|n}`

Answer (score 8):

You can set the paperclip image fields in your factory, which will cause paperclip to not even attempt to process the image:

```
factory :asset do        
  # Set the image fields manually to avoid uploading / processing the image
  image_file_name { 'test.jpg' }
  image_content_type { 'image/jpeg' }
  image_file_size { 256 }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This would be fine, but I need a real image existing in upload path, for instance, `public/system/assets/images/000/000/001/medium/test.jpg`. The feature spec would fail if there's a 404 when requesting images.

Comment: You might still be able point the image_file_name to your Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/sample.jpg').

Comment: I need all of the original, large, medium and small pictures exist in their directories as well. I think this approach wouldn't generate these files.